# listen for events in c++

Tags: c++, events, mfc

I got a CWnd like thie `CWnd * pWnd = pDC->GetWindow();`
Is there away I can be notified when the windows is closing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use Windows Hooks.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632589(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I've not done MFC for years so don't know if this will work but can you:

1. call CWnd::Detach() to get the handle of the window
2. Attach it to your own derived CWnd, with a CWnd::Attach() and have an override of afx_msg void OnClose( );